# Preguntas buenas sin visto bueno

Tags: característica-nueva, respuesta-aceptada, respuesta-propia

Hay preguntas en stackoverflow que tienen respuestas que son mejores que las que han recibido el visto bueno. Quisiera saber si la comunidad hace algo para que los que preguntan den el visto bueno a aquel que responde más correctamente. Por ejemplo yo hice una pregunta y di un visto bueno a alguien, pero al cabo de unos días alguien dio otra respuesta que era mejor. Me vi obligado a cambiar el visto bueno a la mejor respuesta.

Tengo una respuesta publicada y el que pregunta hace referencia a un programa de adobe que yo uso. Hay una respuesta anterior a la mía que no cumple con lo que se pregunta. El propio autor de la pregunta dice que no le sirve la respuesta, pero le dio el visto bueno. Mi respuesta cumple exactamente con lo que pregunta, sin embargo el visto bueno lo tiene otra respuesta que no es buena. **Sería interesante que hubiera una revisión por parte de la Comunidad frente a respuestas buenas que claramente son mejores que otras y que no obtienen lo esperado**.

Comment: La propia comunidad ya se encargará de dar puntos posiivos a la respuesta que crea que es más buena... Piensa que aunque haya una aceptada yo siempre miro la más votada :)

Comment: Ah bueno. Gracias @MiquelColl

Comment: Aún así entiendo perfectamente lo que dices... A veces veo una pregunta con una respuesta aceptada que no soluciona el problema de la forma correcta y publico una respuesta igualmente, así, si en un futuro, alguien tiene el mismo problema quizá lo pueda solucionar con la otra respuesta. Aunque haya una respuesta aceptada eso no significa que el resto no sean válidas.. Siempre intento ser objetivo en ese sentido :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La situación de la que hablas nos ha pasado a todos y es que depende del autor de la pregunta dar el visto bueno, la comunidad no puede hacer nada al respecto ya que violaría las reglas que rigen a StackOverflow.

Esta es una captura de la página del [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio.

[image: modelo]

También en el centro de la ayuda se menciona nuevamente como funciona el [modelo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) de StackOverflow

> Cuando un usuario recibe una buena respuesta a su pregunta, el usuario tiene la opción de "aceptar " la respuesta. La aceptación se indica con una marca de verificación de color junto a la respuesta que ha sido aceptada por el autor original de la pregunta.
>
> La aceptación de una respuesta no está destinada a ser una declaración definitiva y última que indica que la pregunta ya ha sido contestada perfectamente. Simplemente significa que el autor recibió una respuesta que funcionó para él o ella en lo particular, pero no todos los usuarios regresan a aceptar una respuesta, y de los que lo hacen, podrían no cambiar la respuesta aceptada si una mejor respuesta nueva, llega posteriormente.

Yo incluso me he encontrado respuestas que se pueden considerar canónicas con cero puntuación. En este aspecto la comunidad sí puede hacer algo dando votos positivos y quizás divulgandola en el chat para que más personas den sus votos positivos si consideran que cumple los estándares de calidad para convertirse en una respuesta de referencia o canónica. Quizas de esta forma se logre que el autor de la pregunta haga lo correcto y le de la aceptación a la respuesta que la merece.

Comment: Recorrido del sitio: "Aceptar una respuesta no quiere decir que sea la mejor, solo quiere decir que le sirvió a la persona que formuló la pregunta". En mi caso y la pregunta a la que me refiero, el que preguntó dice claramente que no le sirvió la respuesta, aún así le dio el visto bueno. Mi respuesta da una solución exacta a su pregunta, pero de momento no tiene lo que le corresponde. quizás probaré el chat.

Comment: @MarcLemien qué pregunta es?

Comment: El programa al que hace referencia la pregunta es Adobe Muse

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que sucedan esos casos. La única persona que puede cambiar la respuesta aceptada es quien publicó la pregunta. En caso de existir respuestas mejores o más actualizadas, entonces la comunidad puede apoyar a eso mediante los votos a favor de la respuesta que vean mejor. Esto sucede más a menudo de lo que parece, pero para eso está la comunidad, para indicar cuál respuesta les parece mejor.